# restoring function not working using mysql and c#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, winforms, database-restore

I am trying to restore the database  file(backup.sql) using `c#` by the following method...

```
                string hostaddress = "localhost";
                try
                {
                  string pathforbackupfile = @"C:\folder\Access\backupdb\backup.sql";
                  StreamReader file = new StreamReader(pathforbackupfile);
                  string input = file.ReadToEnd();
                  //file.Close();

                  ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                  psi.FileName = @"C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin\mysql.exe";
                  psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                  psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                  psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

                  psi.Arguments = string.Format(@"-u {0} -h {1} {2}", "root", hostaddress, "access");
                  psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                  Process p = Process.Start(psi);
                  //p.StandardInput.WriteLine(input);
                  p.StandardInput.Write(input);
                  p.StandardInput.Close();
                  p.WaitForExit();
                  p.Close();
```

but i have failed to restore the database..

what is wrong with the above code..

**EDIT :**

this is my one of the table structure  :

```
--
-- Table structure for table `banks`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `banks`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `banks` (
  `bank_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bank_Tag` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bank_Name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bank_Address1` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `bank_Address2` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `bank_Address3` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `bank_Town` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `bank_County` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `bank_Postcode` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `bank_Country` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UK',
  `bank_Contact` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bank_Phone` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bank_Email` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `bank_SortCode` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00-00-00',
  `bank_Active` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'yes',
  PRIMARY KEY (`bank_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `banks`
--

LOCK TABLES `banks` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `banks` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `banks` VALUES (1,'ne','asd','asdf','df','df','df','df','sdf','df','df','df','sdf','sdf','y');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `banks` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of a function I wrote long time ago.
Hope this helps:

```
    private MySqlConnection NewConnection(string host, int port, string database, string user, string password)
    {
        if (port <= 0) port = 3306;
        string cstr = "";
        if (database == "")
            cstr = String.Format("SERVER={0};PORT={1};UID={2};PWD={3}",
                host, port, user, password);
        else
            cstr = String.Format("SERVER={0};PORT={1};DATABASE={2};UID={3};PWD={4}",
                host, port, database, user, password);
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cstr);
        try { conn.Open(); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            conn = null;
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public int ExecuteScript(MySqlConnection conn, string sql)
    {
        err = "";
        int totrows = -1;
        if (conn == null) return totrows;
        if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        try
        {
            totrows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd = null;
            return totrows;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err = ex.Message;
            return 0;
        }
    }

public bool Restore(string dbHost, int dbPort, string dbUser, string dbPassword, string file)
{
    int toterr = 0;
    int totsql = 0;
    string msql = "";
    StreamReader rd = null;
    FileStream fs = null;       

    MySqlConnection conn = NewConnection(dbHost, dbPort, "", dbUser, dbPassword);
    if (conn == null) return false;
    int cur = 0;
    int rows = 0;

    fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
    rd = new StreamReader(fs);
    while (rd.Peek() > 0)
    {
        string t = rd.ReadLine().Trim();
        if ((t == "") || (t.StartsWith("--"))) continue;
        msql += t;
        if (msql == ";") msql = "";
        if (msql.EndsWith(";"))
        {
            string s = msql.Remove(msql.Length - 1, 1).Trim();
            msql = "";
            try
            {
                rows = ExecuteScript(conn, s);
            }
            catch
            {
                toterr++;
                break;
            }
            finally
            {
                cur++;
            }
        }
    }
    rd.Close();
    rd = null;
    fs.Close();
    fs = null;

    conn.Close();
    conn = null;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: where are these two functions "rows = ExecuteScript(conn, s);"  and "NewConnection(dbHost, dbPort, "", dbUser, dbPassword);" i have got the errors at these two functions.....

Comment: @rockyashkumar: here they are, take a look

Comment: @Macro its not working  ,i did not drop the database before restoring, may be this is the cause , but i dont know and i am not sure ....would you pls suggest any idea

Comment: @rockyashkumar: my function works, be sure, I use it (an extended version) in some commercial product I develop!! Why it doesn't work for you? I don't know. How did you create your backup? Which error do you receive? Executing my function inside VS, which line breaks with an error? Why?

Comment: @Macro its working fine , but it does not overwrite the data and tables for already existing  data and table names .. it will creates the new database with the name that i have given in that code...that is not what i want ,, i wanted  it to be override the existing data......

Comment: @rockyashkumar: this code is thought to restore a db from a complete backup. So in your SQL file you should have `DROP table ... IF EXISTS` for every table!! And before these lines there should be lines to disable foreign keys check. If you don't have these lines I can't help you

Comment: @Macro see my edit in question that is structure for one of the table in the database, all tables are in that format only , would you pls suggest any solution..

Comment: @rockyashkumar: do you execute this script as "root"? Do you have privilegs to drop tables in that database? If so, try to execute (with my code) `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `banks`;` and check what happens (if code was succesful and if database is updated)

Comment: i execute the script as a root and i don't have privileges to drop the table .....when i specify new name in database name  ,it is creating all tables with the data in that given specified database name .....but when i given a already existing database name with one more tables , it does not create any tables and it does not overwrite the data for the given specified already existing database

Answer (score 0):

What @Marco has given is a better way to approach it since you won't be depending on an external application file for executing your code.

But if you want to execute a text file with SQL statements inside the `mysql` client then you need to pass it as an argument to the `source` command. And I guess you need to change the backslash in the path to forward slash

so instead of `p.StandardInput.Write(input);` you would use `p.StandardInput.Write("source "+pathforbackupfile.Replace( '\\', '/' ) );` in your code.